# How do you give permissions to ASP.NET AJAX Toolkit in web.config?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, permissions, ajaxcontroltoolkit, web-config

I've been trying to add the ASP.NET toolkit to my web application and I can get the demo site to work but I can't seem to implement any of the controls in my application.  After playing around with it for a while, I think I've found the problem.  In my web.config, I have:

```
<authorization>
    <allow roles="Users"/>
    <deny users="*"/>
</authorization>
```

If I change it to:

```
<authorization>
    <allow roles="Users"/>
</authorization>
```

Then everything works wonderfully.  Is there a set of permissions I need to include to get the Toolkit to work?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you elaborate on how things are 'not working'??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What errors are you seeing?

Have you checked that scripts are being delivered correctly to the browser ([Firebug](http://getfirebug.com) makes it very easy to see all the called scripts, and their contents for example)?

If you're calling a page method, have you checked the responses coming back from your pages (once again, Firebug is your friend here - the console will show you the AJAX requests being sent and the responses from the servers).

I've just set up a quick test harness with an autocomplete extender from the AjaxToolkit on a page that is locked down in a similar way to how you describe, and it all worked fine - how have you configured the ToolkitScriptManager?

Comment: Thank you so much!!  I found the error I missed previously (Firebug is much better than what I was using!) and it was: 

"Sys.Extended is undefined"

After searching for that specific error, I found these bug reports and solutions:

http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/workitem/26755?ProjectName=ajaxcontroltoolkit
http://forums.asp.net/t/1563310.aspx

So switching from using the toolkit's ScriptManager to using the ASP.NET 4.0 ScriptManager fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Had problem with IE 8.0 and AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUpload
with the authorization configuration:

```
<authorization>
    <allow roles="Users"/>
    <deny users="*"/>
</authorization>
```

Solution was to define in web.config:

```
  <location path="AjaxFileUploadHandler.axd">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>

  <location path="CombineScriptsHandler.axd">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>   </location>
```

If the file where you instance AjaxFileUpload is in a folder in the website ex) foobar must the location be:  `<location path="foobar/CombineScriptsHandler.axd">

<location path="foobar/AjaxFileUploadHandler.axd">`